# Replacing a NaN value with null in DataGrid in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, nan, advanceddatagrid, labelfunction

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('column 1')}" dataField="datafield1" labelFunction="getTotalQty"/>


private function getTotalQty(inData:Object, inCol:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String
        {
            return (isNaN(inData.qty)?"":inData.qty);
        }
```

currently this returns an empty data grid cell for each cell. irrespective of whether the cell is NaN or has a number in it.

the datagrid is passed several objects, object 0 has NaN and thus returns a null box, object 1 has value 70 and still returns a null box.

Answer (score 0):

inData is a generic object; which probably means that qty is also untyped; as it is not a default property on object.  That would be why it fails the isNaN test.  Try casting inData to your custom object or casting inData.qty to a Number.

Something like this:

```
private function getTotalQty(inData:Object, inCol:AdvancedDataGridColumn)
{
            var qtyAsNumber : Number = Number(inData.qty);
            return (isNaN(qtyAsNumber)?"":qtyAsNumber.toString());
}
```

Comment: I have had the same outcome when using this method, I removed the colon from your code to get it to compile but it didn't work for me. is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Run your code in debug mode; and see what happens in the method by looking at the variables.  Perhaps inData.qty is not a Number?  Can you provide a full runnable sample?

Comment: thanks very much it works for 1 column now. inData.qty was not a number and I was able to get it working by calling inData.ColumnName however I need this label formatter to work on multiple columns, which obviously all wont have the same name. However the object inData only holds all the column names and their values so I cant see a way of doing this without a different formatter for each column. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: also if their is no datagrid at all in the datagrid the column which the label formatter have been applied to will show up with 0 in them? can i change that to display nothing. Thanks

Comment: *no data in the data grid not no datagrid at all in the datagrid. apologies